# Borel sum of $ 1!+2!+3!+.... $

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I know that the Borel sum of $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n! $ is $ \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x} $

but what happens with the sum $  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n! $

the Borel sum should be $ \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x} $ which has a pole at $ x=1 $  using Shothotsky's formula I get

$$ PV  \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}-i\pi e^{-1} $$

however this is a complex number.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748286/regularizing-the-sum-of-all-factorials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have asymptotic series
$$
e^{-x} \text{Ei}(x) \sim \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j!}{x^{j+1}}
\qquad \text{as } x \to +\infty
$$

We can interpret "Borel summation" as: "Let's plug in $x=1$, even though the series diverges there!"
$$
e^{-1}\text{Ei}(1) \approx 0.69717488
$$

Comment: Cool!  Is this the case with most divergent asymptotic series?

Comment: Here's a book for you: Ovidiu Costin, *Asymptotics and Borel Summability* (Monographs and Surveys in Pure and Applied Mathematics)

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: Mathematica gives -Subfactorial[-1] which is a complex number (its real part coincides with your answer)

Answer (score 1):

*(This should be a comment to @GEdgar's answer, but does not fit the input-box)*

In [an article](http://www.math.uoc.gr/~ictm2/Proceedings/pap38.pdf%E2%80%8E) we find a curious discussion about Maple summing this series to a complex value where the real value is that which GEdgar points out.

I just insert the screenshot (don't have the software to extract the text nicely):
(...)

[image]

(...)
It reminds the reader, that things are far from trivial...